# I did not find migrations Samll/Tiny methods in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Trying to use new migrations methods for laravel 8
I found method :

```
foreignId() - The foreignId method is an alias of the unsignedBigInteger method:
```

I did not find are there relative methods for Tiny and small unsigned types?

and similar questions for id()

```
The id method is an alias of the bigIncrements
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types) and the [API docs for the blueprint class](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html) to see the available types.

Comment: Thanks for this link , but with methods foreignId, I searched for methods like 
foreignTinyId, foreignSmallId, and tinyId, smallId.
and did not find,  looks like there are aliases only for big type...

Comment: That's right. Those aliases were introduced when bigIncrements/unsignedBigInteger became the default.